# RegEx to handle Alphanumeric Input - PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have this code.

```
<?php
    $USClass = "3/312";
    $USClass = preg_replace_callback('~[\d.]+/[\d.]+~', function ($matches) {
    $parts = explode('/', $matches[0]);
    return $parts[1] . ',' . $parts[0];
    }, $USClass);
    echo $USClass;
?>
```

It prints 312,3 which is what I wanted.

However, if I give an input like **D12/336** then it does not work. I want it to print **336,D12**

How can I do it? and What is wrong with my current code which is not handling this Alphanumeric? Is it because I used \d ?

**EDIT:**

I want it to handle inputs like this as well

**148/DIG.111**

then the output should be **DIG.111,148**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes `\d` does only contain digits.

You can try `\w` instead this is alphanumeric, but additionally it includes also `_`

To be Unicode you can go for

```
~[\pL\d.]+/[\pL\d.]+~u
```

`\pL` is a Unicode code point with the property "Letter"

The `u` at the end turn on the UTF-8 mode that is needed to use this feature

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

**Other solution**

I think you ar e doing this a bit complicated. It would be simplier if you would make use of capturing groups.

Try this:

```
$in = "148/DIG.111";
preg_match_all('~([\w.]+)/([\w.]+)~', $in, $matches);
echo $matches[2][0] . ',' . $matches[1][0];
```

Explanation:

```
([\w.]+)/([\w.]+)
^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^
Group 1   Group 2
```

Because of the brackets the matched substring is stored in the array `$matches`.

See [here](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) for more details on `preg_match_all`

Comment: Great! This code works!

`<?php
 $USClass = "148/DIG.111";
 $USClass = preg_replace_callback('~[\w.]+/[\w.]+~', function ($matches) {
 $parts = explode('/', $matches[0]);
 return $parts[1] . ',' . $parts[0];
 }, $USClass);
 echo $USClass;
?>`

Comment: @Bhavani Kannan I updated my answer with a Unicode solution. I think the `\w` will only cover ascii letters.

Comment: @Bhavani Kannan I updated my answer again with a maybe better solution.

Answer (score 2):

With a simple preg_replace:

```
$USClass = "148/DIG.111";
$USClass = preg_replace('#(.+?)/(.+)#', "$2,$1", $USClass);
echo $USClass;
```

**output:**

```
DIG.111,148
```